# Dialogflow nodemailer dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Unhandled rejection

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

These are my codes. I get this trouble for two days.
The problem is here.
Back to my firebase log or cloud log. I can see these warning and errors.
please help! Many thanks!

dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Unhandled rejection
3:09:51.256 pm
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error: No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE
at WebhookClient.send_ (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:488:13)
at promise.then (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:306:38)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
admin.initializeApp();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'pakho450059276@gmail.com',
    pass: 'Yinbaihaopakho52***',
  },
});

 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Hi there!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  
  function sendEmailHandler(agent){
    const {email,name}= agent.parameters;
    
    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'pakho450059276@gmail.com', // sender address
      to: email, // list of receivers
      subject: 'Email from dialogflow', // Subject line
      html: `<p>Hello this is ${name}</p>`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  }
  
  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('sendemaill', sendEmailHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I only see 1 thing that may be causing this issue.
`admin.initializeApp();`.

When registering the app on firebase, this variable is created, which is then used to configure the app:

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = { 
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXX"
  };
```

Instead of `admin.initializeApp();`, I believe using this variable and doing `admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` will resolve this issue you are experiencing.